# Question about an equation of kinematics derived with Lagrangian Mechanics

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, dimensional-analysis

In this video https://youtu.be/2o3-GTk72x8, Professor Michel Biezen derives the following equation :

$$mx’’+m\ell \left(\theta’’ \cos(\theta)-\sin(\theta)(\theta’)^2\right) = -kx. $$

However, the terms inside the bracket are not dimensionally equal (the coefficient of $\sin(\theta)$ is not dimensionally equal to Force), so there must be some error in this equation. I cannot figure out exactly where the error as but my best guess is the error comes in after applying the product rule right before this equation is written at 3:47

Comment: Questions on this site are expected to be self-contained. The reader should never be required to watch a video in order to understand the question.

Comment: Hi Vansh, I’ve added MathJax to your post. For the future, you can find a tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @PauloMourão The OP can write the equations from which this is derived.

Comment: I see nothing dimensionally wrong,

Comment: I feel like that would be a lot of work for him to possibly just make it harder for us to spot a possible mistake in the derivation. But I mean, rules are rules, I'm just pointing this out for this specific case.

Comment: But I dont think it is dimensionally wrong, actually

Comment: The OP needs to explain why they think a mass times a length times the square of an angular velocity is not dimensionally a force.

Comment: Vansh, do you agree that $\ell\dot\theta$ is a speed?

Comment: I am extremely sorry about my misunderstanding. the question is wrong. I realize my mistake. I am very sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ is dimensionless, so all the units in that equation are correct. In particular, the dimensions of $\theta’’$ and $(\theta’)^2$ are both $T^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is dimensionally correct.

$\theta$ and $\sin(\theta)$ are dimensionless, so $\dot{\theta}$ has dimensions of $T^{-1}$ and $(\dot{\theta})^2$ has dimensions of $T^{-2}$. Combine this with the $m l$ outside the parenthesis, you get $kg\cdot m\cdot s^{-2}$, which is the unit for Force